# Setting max-height attribute with D3

Tags: d3.js

Can anyone explain why in the script below the right-hand text element does not behave in the same way as the left regarding its height parameter?

(This is a stripped-down script - to see working [here's the jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/wtYt2/))

```
<html>
<style>
#leftbox, #rightbox
{
  width:300px; 
  padding:3px;
  background:#bbb;
  overflow:auto;
}
#leftbox  {
    float:left;
    max-height: 200px;
}
#rightbox {float:right;}
</style>

<div><p id="leftbox">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... etc
</p></div>
<div><p id="rightbox">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... etc
</p></div>

<script>
d3.select("#rightbox").attr("max-height", 200).style("color", "red");
</script>
</html>
```

---

Edit 13.11.13

The working line: `d3.select("#rightbox").style("max-height", "200px").style("color", "red");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is a bit more picky when it comes to setting attributes. You need to use `.style()` and explicitly give the unit "px" for this to work -- http://jsfiddle.net/wtYt2/1/